# How to use Rust's Peekable?

Tags: rust

I'm interested in peeking ahead in a character stream. To my understanding, [Peekable](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html) would be the way to go. I can't *quite* figure out how to use it.

First attempt:

```
fn trawl<I, E>(pk: &mut I) where I: std::iter::Peekable<Result<char, E>> {
    loop {
        let cur = pk.next();
        let nxt = pk.peek();
        match (cur, nxt) {
            (Some(i), Some(nxt_i)) => println!("{} {}", i.ok(), nxt_i.ok()),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    trawl(&mut std::io::stdio::stdin().chars());
}
```

This fails to compile with

```
> rustc /tmp/main.rs
/tmp/main.rs:1:37: 1:73 error: `std::iter::Peekable` is not a trait
/tmp/main.rs:1 fn trawl<I, E>(pk: &mut I) where I: std::iter::Peekable<Result<char, E>> {
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Okay, fair enough. I don't fully understand traits yet so I try to pass an iterator in and then create a peekable version:

```
fn trawl<I, E>(it: &mut I) where I: Iterator<Result<char, E>> {
    let mut pk = it.peekable();
    loop {
        let cur = pk.next();
        let nxt = pk.peek();
        match (cur, nxt) {
            (Some(i), Some(nxt_i)) => println!("{} {}", i.ok(), nxt_i.ok()),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    trawl(&mut std::io::stdio::stdin().chars().peekable());
}
```

This fails with

```
> rustc /tmp/main.rs
/tmp/main.rs:2:18: 2:20 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
/tmp/main.rs:2     let mut pk = it.peekable();
                                ^~
/tmp/main.rs:7:65: 7:70 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
/tmp/main.rs:7             (Some(i), Some(nxt_i)) => println!("{} {}", i.ok(), nxt_i.ok()),
                                                                               ^~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
/tmp/main.rs:7:39: 7:77 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Could someone explain:

- why Peekable couldn't appear in the function type for lack of being a trait,
- what the compiler means when it says 'move out of dereference of' and
- how I might resolve either or both?

---

A third version

```
fn trawl<I, E>(mut it: I) where I: Iterator<Result<char, E>> {
    let mut pk = it.peekable();
    loop {
        let cur = pk.next();
        let nxt = pk.peek();
        match (cur, nxt) {
            (Some(i), Some(nxt_i)) => println!("{} {}", i.ok(), nxt_i.ok()),
            // (Some(i), ) => println!("{}", i.ok()),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    trawl(std::io::stdio::stdin().chars().peekable());
}
```

This fails with:

```
> rustc /tmp/main.rs
/tmp/main.rs:7:65: 7:70 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
/tmp/main.rs:7             (Some(i), Some(nxt_i)) => println!("{} {}", i.ok(), nxt_i.ok()),
                                                                               ^~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
/tmp/main.rs:7:39: 7:77 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I fail to understand what rust is saying to me here, how Iterator.next would have a different return type from Peekable.peek.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Peekable` is not a trait and thus cannot be used as a bound, which would suggest that it could mean one of many types. It is a single, specific, concrete type, `struct Peekable<A, T>`. As you have observed, it’s constructed by calling the `peekable()` method on an iterator, which changes it to something that is peekable.

Here’s how you’d use it if you just wanted to take an iterator:

```
fn trawl<I, E>(iter: I) where I: Iterator<Result<char, E>> {
    let pk = pk.peekable();
    …
}
```

Note also that the `peekable()` method takes self by value; you can’t take a mutable reference to an iterator there.

The alternative which is what you were aiming for but which I would be generally less inclined towards, would be to require the argument to be peekable, putting the burden onto the caller, as you had:

```
fn trawl<I, E>(pk: Peekable<E, I>) where I: Iterator<Result<char, E>> {
    …
}
```

Comment: Note for future readers:  when this answer was written, [`stdin()` was difficult to use safely](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14434).  This is no longer the case, however, as the issue was fixed in Dec 2014.

Answer (score 8):

`Peekable` is actually a struct, not a trait. If you wanted to take a `Peekable`, you could define your function like this:

```
fn trawl<E, I>(it: Peekable<I>) where I: Iterator<Result<char, E>> {
    ...
}
```

Your second implementation is failing to compile because `peek` takes `self` by value (i.e. it *consumes* the iterator, returning a new one), so you can't call it through a `&mut` reference. Most code simply takes the iterator by value instead of by reference:

```
fn trawl<E, I>(it: I) where I: Iterator<Result<char, E>> {
    let it = it.peekable();
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to move the iterator into a function like `trawl`, you can use the `by_ref()` method to create a new iterator that holds onto an `&mut` reference:

```
let mut my_iterator = /* whatever */;
trawl(my_iterator.by_ref());
// my_iterator is still usable here
```

As far as style goes, I would say that the second form is the better way to go, as the first leaks what's basically an implementation detail.

Comment: If the iterator is passed in by value to 'trawl' how would one then iterate through its contents, as that mutates the Iterator? I'm confused about what the correct thing to do here is to achieve--in spirit--what I was going for with the second implementation.

Comment: If the iterator is passed by value to `trawl`, the function owns it, and can do whatever it wants with it. You can do `fn trawl(it: I) { let mut it = it; ... }` to allow iteration over the iterator. There's also a shorthand for this that's exactly identical in semantics: `fn trawl(mut it: I) { ... }`.

Answer (score 5):

Rust has changed a bit since the previous answers. The way to do it now is:

```rust
fn trawl<I, E>(pk: Peekable<I>) 
where I: Iterator<Item = Result<char, E>> {
    …
}
```