# How to fix an error with borrowing peekable iterator twice in Rust?

Tags: rust

### TLDR

How to make the following code compile?

```
let mut iter = (1..3).peekable();
let h = iter.peek();
iter.next();
```

Update: I read [How to use Rust's Peekable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26333439/155423), that is a different question because

1. I don't even have a function here
2. I don't have *move out of dereference of* error here

### Long Story With Background

I'm trying to implement merging of two sorted "streams": I have two iterators both of which produce ordered values, and I need to print values of both of them, also ordered.

For example,

```
(1, 2, 20)
(3, 4, 5, 7)
```

should produce

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 20)
```

The algorithm is simple I compare heads, then print the smaller head and advance the corresponding iterator.

The problem is that I can't wrap my head around lifetimes.

I have some initial implementation which isn't compiling. In order to make my question simpler to answer, I reduced my original implementation to the smallest possible example which fails with the same error as the original.

```
let mut iter = (1..3).peekable();
let h = iter.peek();
iter.next();
```

The error is

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `iter` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/main.rs:47:9
    |
44  |         let h = iter.peek();
    |                 ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
47  |         iter.next();
    |         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
114 | }
    | - first borrow ends here
```

How to fix this error?

I tried to do different things: adding `mut`, `&`, `.by_ref()` everywhere, but obviously, it didn't work because I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: *I also read a bunch of articles and answers to other similar questions here at StackOverflow, but it didn't help.* — **which** did you read, **why** didn't they help? If you don't tell us, then what prevents an answerer from stating the exact same thing you've already read, wasting your time and theirs?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ca6e6e2bf6dda402b34d5fe0f26658e1&version=stable ? Your [mcve] is maybe too simple ;)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26920789/155423; https://stackoverflow.com/q/23969191/155423; https://stackoverflow.com/q/37508081/155423.

Comment: [`itertools::merge`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.4/itertools/fn.merge.html) has already implemented this functionality.

Comment: Oh wow, that's awesome. Thanks @Shepmaster!

Comment: @Shepmaster may I ask what search queries did you use to find those posts?

Comment: [site:stackoverflow.com rust mutable more than once at a time peekable](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20rust%20mutable%20more%20than%20once%20at%20a%20time%20peekable) and [site:stackoverflow.com rust mutable more than once at a time iterator](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+rust+mutable+more+than+once+at+a+time+iterator) — a part of the error message without the variable name in it and then "peekable" and widening out to "iterator".

Comment: What should I do with the question now that it's answered?

Comment: @DNNX: If your answer is in one of the linked questions, please tell us which and we can vote to close as duplicate. If it's the `itertools::merge`, it would be really nice if you answered the question yourself citing the tool and exposing why it works (hint: it uses two phases, first comparing then releasing the borrows, then advancing the right iterator). For bonus points, you can try and implement it for an arbitrary number of iterators (hint: use a heap for efficiency).

Answer (score 1):

The `Option::cloned(&self)` method turns an `Option<&T>` into a `Option<T>`, given that `T:Clone`.  It gets rid of the reference by making a copy of the value.

```
let mut iter = (1..3).peekable();
let h = iter.peek().cloned();
iter.next();
```

Comment: Solving someones problem only enables them to get over that single problem. Explaining why the problem exists and the general approach to solving it will go a lot further.

Comment: Sometimes monkey-see monkey-do is the best way to learn.  We learn by imitation.